# JavaScript Splitting array into two dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Problem: Write a function that splits an array (first argument) into groups the length of size (second argument) and returns them as a two-dimensional array.

Why does my **test2** variable not working?

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  let resArr = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    resArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }
  return resArr;
}
let test = chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
console.log(test);
// returns correct [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]

let test2 = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
console.log(test2);
// should return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]] 
//but returns [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Why?

Thank you!

Comment: _Why?_ --> Because the array `arr` is being mutated/modified within the `for` loop. At each iteration, due to `.splice()`, the length of `arr` reduces by 2. It works in case-1 because the array you passed only has 4 elements. At iteration 1, array reduces to 2 elements & `i` is incremented from `0` to `1`. The check `i < arr.length` becomes `i < 2` and proceeds to next iteration. Now, at iteration 2, array reduces to 0 elements (in your first input - a, b, c, d; but in second input array still has 4 elements). So, for array with 4 elements it worked; but failed for next case.

Comment: In general, one tries to avoid modifying the array over which one is iterating, within the loop.

Answer (score 1):

`arr.length` changing on every iteration. And with incrementing `i` does not full fill condition.

Try below snippet

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  let resArr = [];

  while (arr.length) {
    resArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }

  return resArr;
}

let test = chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
console.log(test);

let test2 = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Since we're using `splice`, we're modifying the length of the original array, which means we shouldn't rely on it to loop through. Instead, we should loop through a range equalling to the length of the array we want to return, which can be calculated by just dividing `inputArr.length / size`.

You can create a "range" and loop through it with a `for..of` loop by using `Array(number).keys()`

```js
const caseOne = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const caseTwo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const caseThree = [1, 'hi', 3, 9, 'a', { hello: 'world' }, 7563, 'c', 3, [1, 2, 3]];

const chunkArray = (arr, num) => {
    // The final array we'll push to
    const final = [];

    // Loop through the future length of the "final" array
    for (const _ of Array(Math.ceil(arr.length / num)).keys()) {
        final.push(arr.splice(0, num));
    }

    return final;
};

console.log(chunkArray(caseOne, 2));
console.log(chunkArray(caseTwo, 2));
console.log(chunkArray(caseThree, 3));
```

You could also use the `reduce` method:

```js
const caseOne = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'];
const caseTwo = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const caseThree = [1, 'hi', 3, 9, 'a', { hello: 'world' }, 7563, 'c', 3, [1, 2, 3]];

const chunkArray = (arr, num) => {
    return [...Array(Math.ceil(arr.length / num)).keys()].reduce((acc) => {
        acc.push(arr.splice(0, num));
        return acc;
    }, []);
};

console.log(chunkArray(caseOne, 2));
console.log(chunkArray(caseTwo, 2));
console.log(chunkArray(caseThree, 3));
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using an index `i` which moves forward by **one** element, but meanwhile you're removing **two** per cycle, so the index falls beyond the array length sooner than you expect.

Instead of using an indexed `for`, just use a `while` condition that checks whether your array is empty or not. If it's not empty, countinue `splice`-ing:

```
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {


  let resArr = [];
  
  while (arr.length > 0) {
    resArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }

  return resArr;
}

let test = chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2); 
console.log(test);

let test2 = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2); 
console.log(test2);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
let resArr = [];
    
    for(i = 0; i < arr.length; i += size){
        resArr.push(arr.slice(i, i + size))
    }

    return resArr;
}

let test = chunkArrayInGroups(["f", "b", "c", "d", "d", "b"], 2);
console.log(test);
// returns correct [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]

let test2 = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 3);
console.log(test2);
```

So this would be my method it uses slice instead of splice but this works like a charm.

Comment: Very functional approach, I like it!

Answer (score 0):

Not only does `arr.length` change with every iteration, but the incrementor should be the `size` variable, rather than `+1`

```js
function chunkArrayInGroups(arr, size) {
  let resArr = [], l = arr.length;
  for (let i = 0; i < l; i+=size) {
    resArr.push(arr.splice(0, size));
  }
  return resArr;
}

let test = chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
console.log(test);
// returns correct [["a", "b"], ["c", "d"]]

let test2 = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
console.log(test2);
// should return [[0, 1], [2, 3], [4, 5]] 
//but returns [[0, 1], [2, 3]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you prefer a more functional approach

```js
const chunkArrayInGroups = (arr, size) =>
  Array(Math.ceil(parseFloat(arr.length) / size))
  .fill(0)
  .map((_, i)=> arr.slice(i * size, (i + 1) *size))


let test = chunkArrayInGroups(["a", "b", "c", "d"], 2);
console.log(test);

let test2 = chunkArrayInGroups([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 2);
console.log(test2);
```